# How do modular arithmetic rules hold for modulo with composite numbers?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know that (x*y)%p = ((x%p) * (y%p))%p holds true for a prime p. Is this equation valid when p is a composite number? How do we write this equation when p is a composite number?

Comment: Of course it is

Comment: It is valid. No change required, except for clarity to replace $p$ by $m$.

Comment: Perhaps it is just my browser but just before each instance of $p$ I see the character "%". I am not familiar with this notation.

Answer (score 2):

The map $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/(n\mathbb Z)$ is a ring homomorphism; this means the operations of addition, subtraction, and multiplication in $\mathbb Z/(n\mathbb Z)$ behave in the expected way.

The unusual feature of multiplication in $\mathbb Z/(n\mathbb Z)$ when $n$ is composite is that the product of two nonzero elements can be zero, as in $2\cdot 3 \equiv  0 \mod 6$.